# Rich text, icon problem

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

[image: icon problem!]

This is an output field of Rich Text Area(32768).
which could be the problem?

In visualforce page I wrote:

```
            <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="{!IF(modal, '', 'display: none;')}">
          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <apex:commandButton action="{!manageModal}" value="close"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        To:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!emailAddressTo}" style="width: 300px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedEmailTo}" multiselect="true" size="2">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!EmailAddress}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!addEmailTo}" value="Add" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        CC:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!emailAddressCC}" style="width: 300px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedEmailCC}" multiselect="true" size="2">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!EmailAddress2}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!addEmailCC}" value="Add" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <p style="font-size: 10pt;"><b>Separare gli indirizzi email con ';'</b></p>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <!--<apex:outputText value="{!emailBody}" escape="false" />-->
              <apex:inputField value="{!emailBody.Body__c}"/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <apex:commandButton action="{!sendEmail}" value="Send email"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why does your visualforce page looks like a modal? Could you post the whole code please?

Comment: yes, the rich text area is located inside a modal. this is the code (for the modal):

Comment: @Daniele i think you need this tag `<apex:inputtextarea RichText="True">`

Comment: this tag doesn't work

Comment: What datatype of `Body__c` ??

Comment: Body__c --> Rich Text Area(32768)

Comment: I tried as a `inputfield` and above code is working for me

Comment: I don't understand the issue because yesterday it worked and the code is the same.
I think is a browser problem, I tried with chrome and firefox

Comment: I think it could be an issue with the modal. I suspect the input field of rich text area to be loaded using Javascript at the page loading. So if you're using a modal, the input is hidden at start, so maybe it causes an issue. But I'm not really sure. Could try to add it outside the modal to see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 1):

I found an article about this issue :
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264419&type=1&language=en_US

To solve it, you have to clear your browser history and cache file.